# PHP use of foreach and $this

Tags: php

This is my code for `index.php`. I know I can't use `foreach` outside class. I don't know what to use instead, there might be something else missing too. I get  the error

> Using $this when not in object context

I have a SQL table *gallery* with 6 attributes: `name`, `thumb`, `display`, `original`, `title` and `description`.

I want to list all rows, how am I going to do this if I can't use `foreach` outside class in PHP5?

```
<?php
while (($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) !== false) {
    $data['name'] = $row->name;
    $data['thumb'] = $row->thumb;
    $data['display'] = $row->display;
    $data['original']= $row->original;
    $data['title']= $row->title;
    $data['description']= $row->description;
foreach ($this->data as $row){
    print "{$row['name']} some HTML {$row['thumb']} some HTML {$row['display']} {$row['original']} some HTML {$row['title']} some HTML {$row['description']} ";
}
?>
```

I now have this

```
if (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) == false) exit;
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) !== false) {
    $data['name'] = $row->name;
    $data['thumb'] = $row->thumb;
    $data['display'] = $row->display;
    $data['original']= $row->original;
    $data['title']= $row->title;
    $data['description']= $row->description;
}

foreach ($data as $row) { print "t {$row['title']}"; }
```

what I get is 't t t t t t'
as if I have 6 empty records (Note that I have 6 attributes so its taking the attributes as rows?)

Comment: you can just put that foreach in class method I guess

Comment: There are like a million tutorials on the web how to retrieve data from a MySQL database in PHP, starting here: http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: @GeorgesKmeid I notice you have updated your question. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8880499/461813) below. You __do not__ need to `foreach` over the rows as you're already looping over them with the `while`. If you try the solution in my answer you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 7):

### Removing some confusion

You can use a `foreach` outside a class, but you cannot refer to a class as `$this` outside itself. The [manual describes it thus](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

> The pseudo-variable $this is available inside any class method when
>   that method is called from within an object context. $this is a
>   reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the
>   method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called
>   statically from the context of a secondary object).

Your code should refer to the class using a variable containing an instance:

```
$object = new DataAccess();
foreach($object->data as $row) {
```

### Possible solution in this case

You can refer to the MySQL result object directly in a string without first assigning it to values in an array - see the code below. If you really want an array then you should be using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_object()`.

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) !== false) {
    print "{$row->name} some HTML {$row->thumb} some HTML {$row->display} {$row->original} some HTML {$row->title} some HTML {$row->description}";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two solutions : If your code is inside class, instead of doing

`$data['eee']=...`

do

`$this->data['eee']=...`

If you are outside of class (but works also inside), replace

`foreach ($this->data as $row) {`

with

`foreach ($data as $row) {`

Answer (score 0):

This variable `$this` is only usable when you are in a non-static method. Otherwise you have to use normal variables. `$this` refers always to the current object.

see this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).